# Calling {page-id}/Posts endpoint returns permission error but app is already approved with that permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get a list of public posts from a Facebook page owned by our client to display on their website. This will be called by the server so we cannot use a page token generated from a long lived user token as this will cause issues if the user leaves or changes their password. I have had it working with a test page using this method, but it's unsuitable for this use case.

We have got a system user but I couldn't generate a page access token using the system user access token.  I'm using this endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{{system_user_id}}/accounts?access_token={{system_user_access_token}}
```

When I use this endpoint to get the list of pages and access tokens I get an empty array as the response:

```
{
    "data": []
}
```

Because of this issue, I'm trying to use the app token instead. I'm using the following endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{{page_id}}/posts
    ?fields=id,message,created_time,scheduled_publish_time,full_picture,is_expired,is_hidden,permalink_url,privacy
    &access_token={{app_token}}
```

However I get this response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#10) This endpoint requires the 'manage_pages' or 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS for details.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 10,
        "fbtrace_id": "APHmCARBaef8h71R-f9Zuj8"
    }
}
```

The app has already been approved with the following permissions:

- email
- pages_read_engagement
- default

Also the business has been verified and an admin of the page (not myself) is also an admin of the app. I'm not sure if it's relevant but the page is a public page and I am trying to access public posts only (I don't need user data etc.).

Where am I going wrong with this? Alternatively, how can I use the system user access token to get page posts?

Comment: App tokens don’t encompass any specific permissions.

Comment: _“When I use this endpoint to get the list of pages and access tokens I get an empty array as the response”_ - sounds like you did not correctly connect your system user and the page?